# How many times can a single character start a New Game Plus?

Tags: torchlight-2

The first playthrough brings you from level 1 to 51. After you start NG+, the game starts over at level 51.

How far does this playthrough bring you? Will you get all the way to level 100 on the second playthrough, or does it stop somewhere and make way for a third playthrough with the same character with even more difficult foes?

How many repetitions of NG+ exist, and what are the appropriate level ranges for each?

Comment: Which game are you talking about? New Game Plus is (as far as I know) a generic term for many games that have unlocked stories or modes after you beat the game.

Comment: The OP is talking about Torchlight 2 (hence the `torchlight-2` tag).

Comment: @dymutaos On this site, we use tags to refer to the game in question. The game name should always be found in tags, so it is redundant to put it in the name of the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I completely missed that. My bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- NG+1 starts at level 51.
- NG+2 starts at level 81.
- NG+3 [starts](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/New_Game_Plus) at level 100.
- NG+4 starts at level 120.
- NG+5 [starts](http://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/10hein/so_i_am_in_new_game_5_level_100_engineer_what_now/) at level 120 too.

So yeah, it appears there's no end to how many times you can NG+ — but there's also no point.

These numbers are fixed. If your character has a higher level than 51 at the start of NG+ (my Engineer was level 54 when he made the jump), the game will still start at level 51 and monsters will adjust in their allotted level brackets accordingly.

Before you start planning your wonderful adventure towards and beyond NG+∞, you want to keep in mind that your character can only play in multiplayer with other players in the same New Game Plus tier. That means you will need to start a new character at level 1 to play with friends who are still midway their first quest.

Answer (score 2):

New Game plusses can continue indefinitely. They start becoming extremely challenging at New Game+++, where mobs start at level 120 (versus your level cap of 100).

([Source](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=31428#p279229))

Comment: I also asked for level ranges for each. Where does NG+ end and NG++ start?

Comment: Unfortunately those I don't have immediately at hand, as I'm not even finished with my first playthrough. The level 120 start for NG+++ is from a friend of mine that's there himself, and the infinite NG+ potential is cited from my linked source.